# How to find largest supergroup in polynomial time?

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, gr.group-theory

Let $G \le S_n$, and G acts on set $[n]$ via a map $\pi$: 
$$\pi : G \times [n]\mapsto [n] $$

In Input generating set of $G$ is given.

**Question :** I need to find the largest supergroup $G^{'}$ (generating set) of $G$  in $S_n$ which has same [blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_(permutation_group_theory)) as $G$.

> For all $x \notin \langle G \rangle$
>
> - check whether $\langle G,x\rangle$ has same blocks as $\langle G\rangle$
>
>   - If yes then add $x$ to the generating set of $G$
>   - Else do nothing

This is a brute force algorithm and running time of this algorithm is exponential many operations i.e. $O(n^n)$.

**Question  :** Is there an polynomial time algorithm for the above problem ?

**Motivation :** Isomorphism of hyper-graphs of low rank in moderately exponential time [(see this)](https://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/papers/hypergraphiso.pdf)

Comment: Why the hyperlink from *supergroup*? That seems to reduce the clarity of the question, not enhance it.

Comment: @ Peter Taylor I Have edited the question

Comment: Is $G'$ the commutator subgroup of $G$, or a typo?

Comment: @ Emil Jeřábek  No $G^{'}$ is not the commutator subgroup of $G$

Comment: What is it, then?

Comment: I have edited the question it was typo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this can be solved in polynomial time (and, I think, even in $\mathsf{NC}$).

First, it's easy to reduce to the case of transitive $G$.

Next, find the minimal blocks of $G$. (See e.g. Section 3.6(B) of Dixon & Mortimer.) This can be done by choosing a point $x \in [n]$, and for each $y \in [n]$, $y \neq x$, computing the (undirected) connected components of the orbital digraph generated by $(x,y)$. Each such connected component is a block; take the smallest ones.

If there are $b$ blocks each of size $s$, then the desired group is the wreath product $S_b \wr S_s = (S_b)^s \rtimes S_s$ in its natural action on $[n]$.